# Retro anime with bloody skeletons wielding axes and guns

Tags: story-identification, anime

If someone knows what anime these images are from, please tell me. All I know is that it's from a retro anime from around 1985.

[image: Bloody skeleton holding gun]

[image: Bloody skeletons wielding axes]

Comment: How do you know that it's from a retro anime from 1985?

Comment: Can you identify what elements make this SFF. Also take a look here [on how to ask a good anime ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question).

Comment: @Skooba - A army of axe-wielding/gun-wielding skeletons sounds pretty fantastical to me

Comment: @Valorum seems a big leap from that image. They could have been ax/gun wielding people who just had a load of acid dumped on them. might explain the blood still there too. :-P

Comment: @Skooba - That's a fair point.

Comment: Where did you get the image?

Comment: @Jenayah Had it on my phone for a while

Comment: I added another picture too

Answer (score 9):

This is a screencap from an OVA anime called [Birth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth_(anime)) (AKA バース, AKA Planet Busters, AKA The World of the Talisman).

[image: Birth - Skeleton skull with gunshot wound]

You can watch the full film [here](https://archive.org/details/Birthneo1024AE208045). The relevant scene is at timecode 59:50

Comment: For the record, finding this took me far too long and I wish I'd never started in the first place :-)